# Laravel Eloquent - hasMany + more

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm creating a Survey module in Laravel, with objects `Survey` that `hasMany('SurveyQuestion');` (basically `JOIN`ing surveys.id = survey_questions.survey_id).

However, there are a couple of questions (with survey_id = 0, that doesn't correspond to any `Survey`) that I would like to ask in all surveys (namely, name, email, etc).

Is it possible to rig the hasMany relationship to add those 2 questions (basically `WHERE survey_questions.survey_id = survey_id OR survey_questions.survey_id = 0`)?

Comment: Why would you have an id of zero?

Comment: As he explained, I believe they're "global" questions

Comment: this smells like trouble. Why not just treat those 2 questions as any other question, since you're asking them in each survey anyway? or couple them with the user and treat them as something that happens during the registration process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this on your survey model:

```
public function questions() {
    return $this->hasMany('SurveyQuestion')->orWhere('survey_questions.survey_id', '0');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Have the function that returns the relationship, then have another public function that calls that, and prepends the extra records to the collection.

```
function surveyquestions() {
    return $this->hasMany('SurveyQuestion');
}

function getPaddedSurveyQuestions() {
     $padded = SurveyQuestions::getId0QuestionsHere();
     return $this->surveyquestions()->merge($padded);
}
```

It's rough code, as you will need to find your id=0 SurveyQuestions in a more manageable way, and you might need to use Collection->prepend() instead of merge() to get the padded questions where you want them, but it might give you some direction.